# If Else in Multiple Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please consider the following SQL Schema and statement.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06c46/1/0

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE EcomGroupProductRelation 
(
    GroupProductRelationGroupID varchar(10), 
    GroupProductRelationProductID varchar(10), 
    GroupProductRelationSorting int
);

INSERT INTO EcomGroupProductRelation
    (
        GroupProductRelationGroupID,
        GroupProductRelationProductID,
        GroupProductRelationSorting
    )
VALUES
    ('GROUP1', 'PROD3', 0),
    ('GROUP1', 'PROD7', 1),
    ('GROUP1', 'PROD2', 2),
    ('GROUP1', 'PROD4', 3),
    ('GROUP1', 'PROD6', 5),
    ('GROUP1', 'PROD8', 6),
    ('GROUP1', 'PROD10', 7);

CREATE TABLE EcomProducts 
(
    ProductID varchar(10), 
    ProductName varchar(255), 
    ProductActive int,
    ProductAutoID int Primary Key
);

INSERT INTO EcomProducts
(
    ProductID,
    ProductName,
    ProductActive,
    ProductAutoID
)
VALUES
    ('PROD2', 'My 2. prod', 1, 2),
    ('PROD3', 'My 3. prod', 0, 3),
    ('PROD4', 'My 4. prod', 1, 4),
    ('PROD5', 'My 5. prod', 1, 5),
    ('PROD6', 'My 6. prod', 1, 6),
    ('PROD7', 'My 7. prod', 1, 7),
    ('PROD8', 'My 8. prod', 1, 8),
    ('PROD9', 'My 9. prod', 1, 9),
    ('PROD10', 'My 10. prod', 1, 10);
```

**Statement:**

```
    WITH Temp AS
    (
            SELECT 
                    GroupProductRelationSorting 
            FROM 
                    EcomGroupProductRelation 
            WHERE 
                    GroupProductRelationProductID = 'PROD7'
    ) 
    SELECT 
            GroupProductRelationProductID 
    FROM 
            EcomGroupProductRelation 
    WHERE 
            GroupProductRelationSorting=
            (
                    SELECT 
                            GroupProductRelationSorting 
                    FROM 
                            Temp
            )-1
```

In my example I get the product prior to PROD7, which is PROD3. Unfortunatly this product isn't active due to the `0` in `ProductActive`.

**QUESTION:

 I need the previous product, but only if it is active (a 1 in the `ProductActive` column).

If it is not active, the one prior to that one should be selected.
Is it possible to do so in a single query?**

Comment: what should happen if the last 2 products are not active? should you go back until you find the last active product?

Comment: Does Temp never contain more than 1 row?

Comment: @jarlh Yes always one row

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the previous product for one given product, then you can use a query like this:

```
select TOP 1 p.ProductID
from EcomGroupProductRelation pr join
     EcomProducts p
     on p.ProductID = pr.GroupProductRelationProductID
where p.ProductActive = 1 and
      pr.GroupProductRelationSorting < (select GroupProductRelationSorting
                                        from EcomGroupProductRelation pr2
                                        where pr2.GroupProductRelationProductID = 7
                                       )
order by pr.GroupProductRelationSorting desc;
```

Note: if there is no product, then this query returns no rows.

Comment: Great @GordonLinoff ! :) Thank you! That gives sense. The GroupProductRelationProductID should be a varchar. But then it returns what it should. I can use this, but doesn't quite answer the question asked.

Comment: @Crave . . . In that case, I don't understand the question.

Comment: OK, some of the question, but not all :)
"If it is not active, the one prior to that one should be selected. Is it possible to do so in a single query?" ;)

Comment: can you help me getting the next product - same style? I have tried to make the query you suggested ASC but that doesn't seem to return the correct product.

Comment: @Crave . . . If you have another question, you should ask it as a question.  However, I would expect the next product to be just a reversal of the `<` and `desc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you filter out the inactive products, then you will need to, in a sense, reorder your Sorting column to determine which columns to add.  This can be done via the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, as follows:

```
WITH Temp AS
  (
    SELECT GroupProductRelationSorting 
    FROM EcomGroupProductRelation 
    WHERE GroupProductRelationProductID = 'PROD7'
  ) 


SELECT GroupProductRelationProductID
FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      GroupProductRelationProductID,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupProductRelationGroupID ORDER BY GroupProductRelationSorting DESC) AS RN
    FROM 
      EcomGroupProductRelation 
       INNER JOIN 
      EcomProducts ON 
        GroupProductRelationProductID = ProductID
    WHERE 
      ProductActive = 1 AND 
      GroupProductRelationSorting < (SELECT GroupProductRelationSorting FROM Temp)
  ) x
 WHERE RN = 1
```

Doing it for the 'next product' would involve changing a couple of conditions: reverse the sort order for the `RN` field, and change the `WHERE` clause to show only records greater than the `Temp` value.

```
WITH Temp AS
  (
    SELECT GroupProductRelationSorting 
    FROM EcomGroupProductRelation 
    WHERE GroupProductRelationProductID = 'PROD7'
  ) 


SELECT GroupProductRelationProductID
FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      GroupProductRelationProductID,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupProductRelationGroupID ORDER BY GroupProductRelationSorting) AS RN
    FROM 
      EcomGroupProductRelation 
       INNER JOIN 
      EcomProducts ON 
        GroupProductRelationProductID = ProductID
    WHERE 
      ProductActive = 1 AND 
      GroupProductRelationSorting > (SELECT GroupProductRelationSorting FROM Temp)
  ) x
 WHERE RN = 1
```